# Implementation of the LOWESS-algorithm (local regression data smoothing)

Tags: statistics, matlab, regression

I need to implement the LOWESS-algorithm in a piece of software I am working on.

The LOWESS-algorithm is a type of filter, which applies a locally weighted regression on each data point. In this case, the input data are equispaced and a first degree polynomial (line) is to be fitted for each point. More general information can be found at Wikipedia ([Local Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression)).

I was unable to find an implementation on the web, so based on the sparse information I could find about the algorithm, I fired up MATLAB and made my own implementation. I have compared my version with the built-in MATLAB version (part of the Curve Fitting Toolbox-function "smooth") and it is clear, that my version is not doing exactly what it should.

[Plot of the MATLAB-version of LOWESS (blue) and my implementation (red) for various bandwidths.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SoaBg.png)

My implementation is in the file "lowess4.m" (the number 4 because it is my fourth try of implementing the algorithm). I have made a small test script that compares my version with the built-in version of the algorithm for four different bandwidths. As one can see, the first plot is an overfit -- and for some reason, only the built-in result is plotted (my version returns NaN-values in this case). In the three remaining plots, one can see that my version matches the built-in except for the outer values.

I think that further weighting is applied in the MATLAB-version, so that the outer values does not have that much influence on the result. I am not sure on that.

I would like some help to fix my implementation. Thanks in advance :-)

My test script "lowess4_test.m" is listed below:

```
% Make some test data (18 equispaced y-values)
x1 = 1:18;
y1 = [ 1 3 5 3 -3 9 -4 -2 -1 7 9 8 5 3 -2 0 3 5 ];

% Four test plots, comparing my algorithm (red)
% with the MATLAB built-in version (blue)
figure()
for i=1:4
    bandwidth = [1 4 8 12];
    sy1 = lowess4(y1, bandwidth(i));
    ty1 = smooth(y1,bandwidth(i),'lowess');
    subplot(2,2,i)
    plot(x1,y1,'b.',x1,ty1,'b-',x1,sy1,'r-')
    str = strcat('Bandwidth =', {' '}, num2str(bandwidth(i)));
    title(str);
end
```

My implementation of the LOWESS-algorithim "lowess4.m" is listed below:

```
% LOWESS-smoothing of equispaced data
% Input: List of y-values to be smoothed ("noisy") and bandwidth
% Output: List of smoothed y-values ("smoothy)
function [smoothy] = lowess4(noisy, bandwidth)
    n = length(noisy);          % Number of y-values
    smoothy = zeros([1 n]);     % Empty array of length n to store result

    % For all points in "noisy", do a local linear weighted regression
    for i=1:n
        % Initialize temporary variables
        A = 0;
        B = 0;
        C = 0;
        D = 0;
        E = 0;

        % Calculate span of values to be included in the regression
        jmin = floor(i-bandwidth/2);
        jmax = ceil(i+bandwidth/2);
        if jmin < 1
            jmin = 1;
        end
        if jmax > n
           jmax = n; 
        end

        % For all the values in the span, compute the weight and then
        % the linear fit
        for j=jmin:jmax
            w = weight(i,j, bandwidth/2);
            x = j;
            y = noisy(j);

            A = A + w*x;
            B = B + w*y;
            C = C + w*x^2;
            D = D + w*x*y;
            E = E + w;
        end

        % Calculate a (slope) and b (offset) for the linear fit
        a = (A*B-D*E)/(A^2 - C*E);
        b = (A*D-B*C)/(A^2 - C*E);

        % Calculate the smoothed value by the formula y=a*x+b (x <- i)
        smoothy(i) = a*i+b;
    end

    return
end

% Define the tricube weight function
function w = weight(i,j,d)
    w = ( 1-abs((j-i)/d)^3)^3;
    if w < 0
        w = 0;
    end
    return
end
```

Comment: In your implementation the length of the span `jmax - jmin` gets smaller near the boundaries. It's possible that MATLAB tries to keep the span of the same length everywhere.

Comment: References for the `lowess` procedure in R are:  (1) Cleveland, W. S. (1979) Robust locally weighted regression and smoothing scatterplots. _J. Amer. Statist. Assoc._ *74*, 829-836.  (2) Cleveland, W. S. (1981) LOWESS: A program for smoothing  scatterplots by robust locally weighted regression. _The American Statistician_, *35*, 54. (3) Becker, R. A., Chambers, J. M. and Wilks, A. R. (1988) _The New S Language_. Wadsworth & Brooks/Cole.

Comment: Rahul, yes, the span gets smaller near the boundaries in my version. Acoording to this link from the MATLAB documentation, it seems like it is also the case in the MATLAB version of the algorithm: http://se.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html#bq_6ys3-3
But, the documentation feels more like a general explanation of the algorithms and not the specific MATLAB implementation. So maybe you are right about this. I have found the source code for the MATLAB implementation (in the file "smooth.m") but I have trouble finding out what is going on - also it will be illegal to post here.

Comment: Thanks for the references, BruceET.